# Does Exodus 20:3 and 20:4 explain two commandments?

Tags: hebrew, exodus

Does the pattern suggests that v. 4 begins a new clause, there being no connection, conjunction, etc., which would "bind" it to the preceding.

**Exodus 20:3-4 NKJV**

> 3 “You shall have no other gods before Me.
>   4 “You shall not make for yourself a carved image—any likeness of anything that is in heaven above, or that is in the earth beneath, or that is in the water under the earth;

Why do many record this as one commandment?

Comment: What makes you think the verse number annotations typically found in our Bibles are of any significance to translation/interpretation in the first place? I'm unsure what "evidence" you expect to turn up or on what basis you think a verse marker should or should not be in any particular location.

Comment: Isn't there a way to block all questions offering a "hieroglyphic" interpretation of Hebrew? This joke has gone on long enough.

Comment: This is important to me, whether or not either of you agree. I live my life by this command, If I live it wrong "I WANT TO KNOW", and you just telling me that I am wrong, or calling my research a joke is not going to work.

Comment: I've taken a stab at re-wording/re-working the question. Does that retain the issue you're interested in? I think it makes the question at least answerable. (Hope it helps.) Feel free to roll-back if you think I've missed your point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "traditional" handling of Exodus 20:3-4 (in the numbering of the standard English translations) -- that the current v. 4 is its own clause/sentence, distinct from v. 3 -- ought to be followed for reasons of both syntax (the ways in which words are ordered to form sentences) and semantics (the meanings of the words).

**Syntax**

In this list of commandments, there is a very regular pattern of mostly negative commands (*lōʾ* + verb) mixed with a couple positive ones (vv. 8 and 12). There are some "off-line" comments as well, but this is the "spine" of the list:

> 20:3) *lōʾ yihyeh lĕkā...* [do not have...]
>   4) *lōʾ taʿăśeh...* [do not make...]
>   5) *lōʾ tištaḥĕweh...* [do not worship...]
>   7) *lōʾ tiśśeh...* [do not take...]
>   8) *zākôr...* [remember...]
>   10b) *lōʾ taʿăśeh...* [do not do...]
>   12) *kabbēd...* [honour...]
>   13) *lōʾ tirṣāḥ* [do not murder]
>   14) *lōʾ tinʾāp* [do not commit adultery]
>   15) *lōʾ tignōb* [do not steal]
>   16) *lōʾ taʿăneh...* [do not bear false witness...]
>   17) *lōʾ taḥmōd...* [do not covet...]

Clearly, then, the pattern suggests that v. 4 begins a new clause, there being no connection, conjunction, etc., which would "bind" it to the preceding.

On the other hand, the remainder of v. 4 *does* have such a conjunction. Furthermore, it would be very odd in this regular setting to have a "fragment" as an independent ... "bit" which, if it was separated from its context, might be translated this way:

> 4b) *wĕkol tĕmûnâ ʾăšer baššāmayim mimmaʿal* [and any likeness which is in the heaven above]
>   *wĕʾăšer bāʾāreṣ mittaḥat* [or which is on the earth below]
>   *wĕʾăšer bammayim  mittaḥat lāʾāreṣ* [or which is in the water under the earth]

And, frankly, that just doesn't make much sense as a distinct clause in this context. For good reason has this been taken as an elaboration of the preceding *pesel* "idol, image" at the end of the first clause of v. 4.

**Semantics**

All words have a range of meaning. Their "lexical" value -- in a dictionary, the description of that range -- is something abstract. In any given utterance, context constrains the meaning, and if there is ambiguity ("I'm going to the *bank*") it helps to know if we're dealing with a financier or a fisherman.

In Exodus 20:3-4, the context is "worship", so the various terms ("gods", "idol", "forms", etc.) even if they can bear other meanings in other contexts (or might *slightly* elude us because of the remoteness of the language) still participate in this network of meanings, much as any of the [many English translations](http://biblehub.com/exodus/20-3.htm) attempt to convey.

**Summary**

As ever, when thinking through a text, the better question to ask oneself is "What *does* this mean?" -- and the superficially similar question, "What *can* this mean?" is best resisted.